# Преобразовать строку-предложение так, чтобы каждое слово начиналось с заглавной буквы, НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЯ TITLE(ВАЖНО)

Tags: python, строки

Дана строка-предложение на английском языке. Преобразовать строку так, чтобы каждое слово начиналось с заглавной буквы. При этом желательно не использовать title(не спрашивайте, почему)

```
a = input("Введите строку-предложение на английском языке: ")
c = a[0]
s = c.upper()
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] == " ":
        s = s + a[i]
        v = a[i+1]
        n = v.upper()
        s = s + n
    else:
        s = s + a[i]
print(s)
```

В итоге при вводе: "My name is" у меня получается "My Nname Iis". Как мне избавиться от повторяющихся букв?

Comment: Как насчёт регулярок? `re.sub('^[a-z]|(?<=\s)([a-z])', lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), 'my name is')` ---> `My Name Is`

Comment: я такого не понимаю( Только учусь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чуток подправить индексы

```
if a[i-1] == " ": # <---
    s = s + " "
    v = a[i]      # <---
    n = v.upper()
    s = s + n
```

Comment: А ,можно даже убрать s = s + " " вообще. Тогда вывод будет без лишних пробелов. Очень помогло, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. Понижаем регистр всех букв (это на тот случай если ввод будет содержать и заглавные буквы, можно не делать, если гарантировано, что ввод будет только строчный) - `.lower`
2. Разбиваем строку на список слов - `.split`
3. В каждом слове поднимаем первую букву - `.upper`
4. Обратно собираем список слов в строку - `.join`

```
a = input("Введите строку-предложение на английском языке: ")
s = " ".join([s[0].upper() + s[1:] for s in a.lower().split()])
print(s)
```

Но если очень хочется перебрать все буквы, можно, например, так:

```
a = input("Введите строку-предложение на английском языке: ")
s = a[0].upper()
f = False
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if f:
        s = s + a[i].upper()
        f = False
    else:
        s = s + a[i]
    if a[i] == " ":
        f = True
print(s)
```

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, что дает if a[i] == " ": f = true.

Comment: @НикитаМанджиев `f` - это флаг, который в этом выражении поднимается, если символ - пробел. Далее, на следующей итерации мы проверим флаг, если он поднят - повысим регистр буквы и опустим флаг.

Comment: то есть он принимает значение true? И если f = true, то выполняется if f? Тогда все логично. Да и работает, спасибо

Comment: @НикитаМанджиев да, он принимает значение true если текущий символ - пробел. И на следующей итерации проверяем флаг и выполняем if f. Все верно.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov для таких случаев, название переменных и нужно писать нормально, а не составлять алфавит.

Comment: `s[0].upper() + s[1:]` можно заменить на `s.capitalize()`, правда, это почти тот же самый `title`...

Answer (score 0):

С перебором символов немного покороче и без индексов:

```
a = 'moTHeR washed RamA '  # input("Введите строку-предложение на английском языке: ")
out, pred = '', ' '
for c in a:
    out += c.upper() if pred == ' ' else c.lower()
    pred = c
print(out)
```

```
Mother Washed Rama
```